# Thevenin resistance for bridge circuit

Tags: resistance, thevenin, wheatstone-bridge

[image]

So I've been at this question for a few hours now and i can't seem to get the final answer for a). I know how to find the the resistance of a basic Wheatstone bridge, but i don't know how to find the resistance with the 7 and 8 ohms parallel to the 10 ohms.

hope i was clear and thanks.

Comment: Homework questions with no (shown) attempt at a solution will be closed. Redraw the circuit with the bridge resistors vertical for clarity. Then start combining.

Comment: Let mr. Thevenin rest in peace. In this homework question Rt should be read as "total resistance of the circuit" Thevenin's equivalent is needed for circuits which have voltage or current sources and one wants to examine how the circuit behaves with different other circuits which are in turns connected to two preselected interconnection terminals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the start of an answer. More will follow if you get stuck.

> ... but i don't know how to find the resistance with the 7 and 8 ohms parallel to the 10 ohms.

They are not in parallel. The 7 Ω and 8 Ω are in series with the parallel combination of the 10 Ω and the bridge.